# How to separate interface from technical implementation using Interfaces when there are Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

1. I try to separate the technical implementation and the domain logic interface using Java interfaces.
2. As I also do test driven development, my implementations have to throw exceptions, which are related to technical problems.

Because of `2.` I have to add 'throws' to the interface method declarations too, which clashes with the requirement `1.`.

So my problem is, that I don't want to have implementation specific details in the interface but I want to do test driven development.

My first idea to solve this, is to translate technical exceptions to domain logic exceptions.

Is this the only way to go or do I miss something? Is there an approved design pattern to solve this or any other solution to this problem, because to introduce a lot of custom exceptions will lead to an overhead in development.

Comment: So it's possible that an error can occur, and you want to inform the client of this error (hence why it's being thrown, opposed to caught & handled). But, you don't want the client to know that the interface they're using may throw an exception by including `throws` in the interface? I'm confused.

Comment: I don't want to have implementation specific details in the interface but I want to do test driven development

Comment: So if the exceptions are implementation details, don't throw them. Have the implementation handle it accordingly. Then you won't need to define em in your interface.

Comment: Vince, if the implementation handles them, my unit tests won't fail when they occur. Hence  my first thought was to translate them to another level.

Comment: That's because it's implementation details.. Unit tests ensure the *public* api for a unit works as expected. If the user shouldn't expect exceptions, you shouldn't test for them. If they should, then it should be defined in the public API. One or the other, you can't hide it AND show it.

Comment: I know what the problem is, I am looking for the typical solution for this in a Java context, possibly using a design pattern.

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem.. Your question is similar to "How do I hide something, but make it noticable?" - It's one or the other.. You can't hide the exception, then hope clients (your test, which emulates a user of the API) will notice it. Either don't test for it, or include it in the public API. That *is* the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168874/discussion-between-vince-emigh-and-azure).

Comment: Vince, there are possible solutions to this problem, I already mentioned one. I am currently not interested in chatting with you.

Comment: Your solution is to include an exception in your interface. Hmmm... Sounds like that's been suggested before. But that's fine, I'll avoid helping you in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to solve this problem is to catch the implementation-detail Exception types, and throw a new exception type which is more appropriate to your specific service. If this is what you meant by "translate technical exceptions to domain logic exceptions, then yes, that's the right way to go.

For example, maybe you have a UserRepository interface, and your implementation is currently using SQL to look up the users. You can mark your interface methods as throwing your own exception types (e.g. `UserNotFoundException`). Your implementation catches any SQL-related errors and throws a `UserNotFoundException` instead.

This way, if you switch to using MongoDb or something in the future, your interface stays exactly the same, while your implementation now has to catch the kinds of exceptions that MongoDb throws. The code that consumes your interface continues to work correctly because it knew how to handle the `UserNotFoundException` already, and that hasn't changed.

Remember to include the original exception as the `cause` of the new exception you're throwing so as not to lose the stack trace.

Comment: The OP wants to avoid `throws` in his interface: "*Because of (2) I have to add 'throws' to the interface method declarations too, which clashes with the requirement (1).*"

Comment: @VinceEmigh: As I understood it, his issue is not the `throws` itself, but the fact that he's having to `throws` a type of exception which deals with implementation-level details. This approach fixes that issue. However, if he wants to avoid `throws` entirely, he can make his domain-level exception types extend RuntimeException.

Comment: How would he expose this in the contract for the interface without declaring `throws`? How would users know how to test for it without needing to read the implementation? It would be an undocumented behavior.

Comment: This is a good answer. Altough on a real SQL-error I think it would be better to name the exception InternalServiceErrorException or something similar. I like that you mention the aspect of packaging the implementation exception. I will probably mark this as accepted answer, but will give others a chance to post a (partly) different answer first.

Comment: @VinceEmigh: My recommendation would be that he declares, e.g., `throws UserNotFoundException`, which satisfies the need to separate implementation details from the domain logic, because `UserNotFoundException` is a domain-layer concept. I only mentioned RuntimeException because you seemed to think OP wants to avoid putting `throws` in his interface (which I don't think is the case), and I was pointing out that this same strategy could work for that purpose, too.

Comment: @Azure: Yeah, you know your domain better than anyone, so you can make the call on which type of domain-layer exception makes sense. There's a good argument to be made that "UserNotFound" shouldn't be an exception, but rather a result type or something.